# unable to get char of 2 character long in C

Tags: c

following statement in c gives no error

```
char p='-1';
```

but the following gives error:

```
char p='-12';
```

ERROR: character can be one or two characters long.

I never knew that a char in c can ever be two characters long. However printf("%c",p) gives - as output. Where can i use char in c?

Comment: Giving more than one character in a character constant is implementation-defined IIRC (at least, it's not possible to do so portably). What's your platform?

Comment: What you want is multi-character char literals. They are of type `int` not `char`though...

Comment: @Deduplicator: Multi-character constants are almost certainly *not* what the OP wants. They're very nearly useless.

Comment: @KeithThompson: Well, you are certainly right. Left out "to read about"

Comment: My guess is that you're compiling in an environment where `sizeof(int) == 2`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In C, a character constant like `'A'` does not have type `char`, but rather type `int`. This creates the possibility that, even on a system where `char` is only 8 bits wide (and so `int` is wider than `char`), character constant notations can exist which provide integer values wider than `char`.

The C standard requires implementations to support multi-character constants, but their values are implementation-defined.

Why your compiler allows only two characters is likely because the type `int` is only 16 bits wide. Perhaps a constant like `'AB'` is encoded similarly to, say, the expression `('A' << 8 | 'B')`.  According to the obvious extension of this scheme, `'ABC'` would then have to be `('A' << 16 | 'B' << 8 | 'C')` which doesn't fit into 16 bits and calls for out-of-range shifts. Hence, the two character limit.

In the GNU C compiler, four characters can be used:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
   printf("%x\n", (unsigned) 'ABCD');
   return 0;
}
```

`int` is 32 bits wide, and this program prints `41424344` which, by golly, is hexadecimal for the ASCII characters `ABCD`.  So this feature is useful for `int`-wide magic constants which are readable. Instead of:

```
#define MAGIC 0x41424344  /* This spells ABCD; easy to spot in memory dumps */
```

You can do this, which is nice, but less portable:

```
#define MAGIC 'ABCD'
```

What if we use five or more characters, like `'ABCDE'`? Then GCC respond similarly to how Turbo C++  responds for three or more:

```
test.c:5:35: warning: character constant too long for its type [enabled by default]
```

It so happens that the program still compiles, and its output is unchanged: the `E` was truncated.

There is an important difference. The old Borland compiler is rejecting the excessively-long constant as an error. Though that is probably a good idea, it is not standard-conforming; when some value is implementation-defined,  the implementation's response cannot be failure, such as stopping the translation or execution of the program. Issuing a diagnostic is fine, of course.

Comment: It's not an extension as such. Multi-character constants (of any length) must be supported by all conforming compilers. Their values are merely implementation-defined.

Comment: @Kaz please refer to this link:
https://ideone.com/Y2Bq3o

Answer (score 0):

```
char p='-517';
printf("%c\n", p);
```

Running the above code gave me output `7` and a warning: *overflow in implicit constant conversion [-Woverflow]*

`char` can not contain more than 1 byte of information

Comment: got it....... in visual c++, getting 7, but in turbo c getting that error........... didn't get the concept...........

Comment: @user3437973 seems like `char` will be assigned the byte number 0 whatever your attempt to force it having more than that

Answer (score 0):

You want an array of characters, also known as a C-string

```
// Note, if you initialize a character array with a literal string
// there is no need for a size specifier
char c[] = "-12";

// Note this is a method of copying one character array into another.
#include <string.h>
char c[4];
strcpy(c, "-12");
```

You'll notice that char c[4] has an indicated size of 4. Meaning, the array can only hold 4 characters. In C, character arrays have a special property: A null terminator (char '\0') is a sentinel value that C-string functions use to recognize the end of your string. So, in reality, a character string "-12" is of size 4. '-', '1', '2', and '\0'.

You can also access individual elements of an array by passing an indice to it's operator[] function.

```
printf("%s\n", c);
printf("%c\n", c[0]);
```

Notice the c[0] call, This will access the character '-' of the string "-12".

Hope I helped.

Comment: thanks... but i just wanted to know the concept of char of two character long in c...

Comment: Looks like I read the question a little too quickly, sorry about that. Like Drew McGowen said, it's implementation-defined.